# Legal comfort running

Tags: discussion, tags

**Legal**

There are currently 13 [questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) tagged [legal](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal).

No tag wiki excerpt.

According to the [help center](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), legal issues are *off-topic*. Of the 13 questions, 5 have been closed.

If you are looking for a parenting approach, [legal](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) seems unnecessary. If not, is the question really on topic? Especially considering that there is [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/)? A tag like [legal](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) is only necessary for questions about legality of something, but should this be our focus? Note that there are already tags that touch upon law or legal issues, like [custody](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/custody) or [adoption](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adoption) and they may already be sufficient.

The only [question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/3382/30519) I found where it seems appropriate is a list-type of question that's a bad fit for the SE model anyway. And a broader tag, that's applicable to more questions, may be better for such cases.

---

**Comfort**

There are currently 6 [questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comfort) tagged [comfort](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comfort).

No tag wiki excerpt.

It looks a bit like a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) to me and I'm not sure what it's trying to say. If it's about how *to comfort* someone, it should rather be [comforting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comforting). But it seems easier and more convenient to tag it with the goal instead, e. g. the often used [emotional-well-being](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotional-well-being).

The only [question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/24107/30519) where [comfort](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comfort) seems appropriate could do very well without it and [emotional-well-being](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emotional-well-being) instead.

---

**Running**

There are currently 3 [questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/running) tagged [running](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/running).

No tag wiki excerpt.

For sports, we already have tag [sports](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sports) and if it's about children learning how to walk, there's [walking](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/walking). Instead, [running](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/running) seems overly specific and was therefore seldomly used. The older two questions actually can do without that tag and I would add [sports](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sports) instead, while the [newest one](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/34393/30519) may need neither [walking](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/walking) nor [running](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/running), but [discipline](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discipline) instead.

---

**What do you think about these tags? Are they needed or not?**

Answer (score 1):

I hate to be so wishy-washy, but I don't want you to think your question is being ignored. So...

I agree that *legal* is off topic, but if we destroy it, it will come back like a noxious weed (or a not-noxious one.) I think those should either be closed or migrated.

'How to comfort' questions aren't always apparent to the OP as involving emotional well being, so I'd say 'comforting' is a good alternative.

Running can be a sport or a misbehavior, and it could be a milestone as well. I can imagine someone asking a milestone question about running. Maybe an edit for running asking that if it's about a milestone, use milestone instead? Otherwise I see no other need for running.

Comment: *Legal*: They are too old to be migrated. I looked at the open ones and, except for [1](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/24766/30519) and [2](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/3382/30519), it seemingly could be removed without impairing the questions. *Comfort*: I see 2 questions, [3](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/24107/30519) and [4](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/23530/30519), for which *comforting* would be appropriate (I added *comfort* to 4). *Running*: I agree about the milestones but there's so far no question about it (the oldest is about a fun experience).

Comment: @AnneDaunted - Sorry I wasn't more clear; I meant in the future. :(